# ORA-00988: missing or invalid password(s)

Tags: oracle, passwords, createuser

I'm trying to change an oracle password:

```
alter user FOO identified by 'BAR';
```

and I'm getting the following back:

```
Error starting at line 120 in command:
alter user FOO identified by 'BAR'
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00988: missing or invalid password(s)
00988. 00000 -  "missing or invalid password(s)"
```

What's going on?

Comment: Remove the **single-quotation marks** around the password followed by the `identified by` clause.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Turns out one doesn't put the password in single quotes.  Double quotes are required if the password contains some special characters.

```
alter user FOO identified by 'BAR'; -- Broken
alter user FOO identified by BAR;   -- Works
alter user FOO identified by "BAR"; -- Works
```

Comment: Reviewing version 12c, Oracle documents this requirement under [CREATE USER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503) but unfortunately not under [ALTER USER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4003.htm#SQLRF01103).

Comment: At least the error could be "unexpected token '  at..." or something...

Comment: Your comment about double quotes saved me, who uses password without special characters?

Comment: Double quotes worked in my case, and the password didn't contain special characters, it was a simple 1234 password

Comment: @AdriánJaramillo - Right, in that scenario quotes were acceptable but optional. If you'd had special chars, the double quotes would've been required.

Answer (score 3):

alter user davidl identified by "newpassword" replace "oldpassword";

Answer (score 0):

For me I was altering two users in the same script file, which did not work. I had to alter them in a different script files.

Sql tool: Golden